# Kivy updating label when using function via button fails

Tags: python, function, kivy, label, updating

I'm trying to build an App thats uses certain input Parameters and when hitting a submit button it uses a logic to generate output paramters. I managed to build the app and the input and the triggering via a submit button. Now i want to generate the output, for beginning with an easy logic. I looked up several similar solutions, but somehow they don't work for me.
For some reason my .kv file doen't get the updated value for the label text with the error: "ValueError: Label.text accept only str" Eventough everything is declared as a string in the .py. If i change it in the kv to str("...") I get some code line which i guess is the intern id of the attribute but not the assigned value i want to get.
I hope you can help. Pls don't be too harsh, I#M new to python and kivy...

main .py, shuldn't be part of the problem
**Peenomat.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase


Builder.load_file('Statusbar.kv')
Builder.load_file('Inputparameters.kv')
Builder.load_file('Outputparameters.kv')


#Layout
class Peenomat(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class PeenomatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Peenomat()

if __name__=="__main__":

    PeenomatApp().run()
```

.py with the classes and methods for the logic
**StatusBar.py**

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.app import App




class InputParameters(GridLayout):

    verfahren = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_state(self, togglebutton):
        tb = togglebutton
        if tb.state == 'down':
            self.verfahren = tb.text
            self.verfahren = tb.text
            print(self.verfahren)
            return self.verfahren


class StatusBar(BoxLayout):
    #InputGrößen
    group_mode = False
    prozess = ObjectProperty(None)
    vorbehandlung = ObjectProperty(None)
    material = ObjectProperty(None)
    haerte = ObjectProperty(None)
    rauheit = ObjectProperty(None)

    #OutputGrößen
    frequenz = StringProperty(None)

    def btn_submit(self):

        ip = App.get_running_app().root.ids._input_parameters
        print("Haerte:", ip.haerte.value, "Rauheit:", ip.rauheit.value, "Material:", ip.material.text, "Vorbehandlung:", ip.vorbehandlung.text)


        if ip.haerte.value < 50:
            self.frequency = str(180)
        elif ip.haerte.value < 60:
            self.frequency = str(200)
        else:
            self.frequency = str(220)
        #control to see if right value is taken
        print(self.frequency, "Hz")

    def btn_clear(self):
        np = App.get_running_app().root.ids._input_parameters
        np.pro1.state = "normal"
        np.pro2.state = "normal"
        np.pro3.state = "normal"
        np.material.text = "Auswahl treffen"
        np.haerte.value = 55
        np.rauheit.value = 5.5
```

the .kv file that can't get the label text:
**outputparameters.kv**

```
#: import statusbar StatusBar

<OutputParameters@GridLayout>

    #Initialisierung .py zu .kv
    frequenz: _frequenz

    Label:
        text:'Frequenz:'
        font_size:

    Label:
        id: _frequenz
        text:  root.frequenz
        font_size: 20
```

the .kv file with the submit button, shouldn't be part of the problem either, worked perfectly fine before implementing the part ehre i try to update the text
**statusbar.kv**

```
#: import statusbar StatusBar

<StatusBar@BoxLayout>

    orientation:'horizontal'

    Button:
        text: 'Clear'
        on_press: root.btn_clear()

    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.btn_submit()
```

the file where i put in all the inputparameters, rather important:
**Inputparameters.kv**

```
#: import statusbar StatusBar

<InputParameters@GridLayout>
    #Initialisierung .py zu .kv Ids
    prozess: _prozess
    pro1: _prozess1
    pro2: _prozess2
    pro3: _prozess3
    vorbehandlung: _vorbehandlung
    material: _material
    haerte: _haerte
    rauheit: _rauheit


    #Prozess
    Label:
        text:'Prozess:              

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        id: _prozess

        ToggleButton:
            id:_prozess1
            text:'P-MOH'
            group: "proc_group"
            on_state: root.on_state(self)

        ToggleButton:
            id:_prozess2
            text:'E-MOH'
            group: "proc_group"
            on_state: root.on_state(self)

        ToggleButton:
            id:_prozess3
            text:'PE-MOH'
            group: "proc_group"
            on_state: root.on_state(self)

    #Material
    Label:
        text: 'Material:'            

    Spinner:
        id: _material
        text: ""
        values: 

    # Herstellschritte
    Label:
        text:'Fertigungsschritte:'

    Spinner:
        id: _vorbehandlung
        text: 
        values: 

    # Haerte
    Label:
        text:'Haerte:'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: str(_haerte.value) 

        Slider:
            id: _haerte

    # Rauheit
    Label:
        text:'Rauheit:             

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: 

        Slider:
            id: _rauheit
```

and the file where my layout is embedded (also rather necessary)
**peenomat.kv**

```
<Peenomat>

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            InputParameters:
                id:_input_parameters

            StatusBar:
                id:_status_bar

            OutputParameters:
                id:_output_parameters
```

I really hope you can help, have been struggeling with this for a while and it should rather be easy...thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your codes on minimal level ? It's hard to understand.I don't have your Fonts and Header,Statusbar,Inputparameters,Outputparameters .kv files. Edit and crop useless parts please i can't focus and correlate between codes.

Comment: sorry that's my second thread here...I updated the code. Hope it'seasier like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv` rule for `<OutputParameters@GridLayout>` you have a line:

```
frequenz: _frequenz
```

which sets `frequenz` to be a reference to the `Label` with the `id` of `_frequenz`. Then in that `Label` you are setting `text` using:

```
text:  root.frequenz
```

So, you are trying to set the `text` of the `Label` to a reference to that `Label`

I suggest trying something like this:

```
<OutputParameters@GridLayout>

    #Initialisierung .py zu .kv
    frequenz: _frequenz
    frequency: ''
```

And change the `Label` to:

```
Label:
    id: _frequenz
    text:  root.frequency
    font_size: 20
```

But to actually change the value shown in the label, you will need a reference to the instance of `OutputParameters`, using something like:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids._output_parameters.frequency = str(500)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error is gone now. But like you mentioned I won't get the value for frequency to my .kv-file. I updated the post, added the file names and the missing file. Should be complete now on a minimal level.

Comment: Still not enough information to provide a complete answer (I don't see where an instance of `OutputParameters` is created). However, I noticed another error. Where you are using `InputParameters.verfahren`, it should actually be `self.verfahren` in the `on_state()` method.

Comment: That's all the information i can provide. Thats all the scripts i got and the App is running like that...
I don't quite get the instance you're suggesting. What should it look like? You mean something like the         `ip = App.get_running_app().root.ids._input_parameters` I did for the InputParameters? Thought this only works to get something out of the .kv-file to .py not the other way around?

Comment: I have added more information in my answer using the information that you recently posted.